# Storing Array of Void Pointers

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

I'm working on a shared library for Arduino. In my interrupt attachments, I need to declare an interrupt service routine with a type of `void(*)()`.

I pass in an array of void functions that I then loop through to populate a property on the object as follows:

MainUnit.h

```
class MainUnit {
public:
    MainUnit(const String type,
             const int revisionNumber,
             const int totalInputs,
             uint8_t avrPinNumbers[],
             uint8_t spdtPinNumbers[],
             void* isrs[]);

private:
    void* InterruptServiceRoutines[];
};
```

MainUnit.cpp

```
MainUnit::MainUnit(const String type,
                   const int revisionNumber,
                   const int totalInputs,
                   uint8_t avrPinNumbers[],
                   uint8_t spdtPinNumbers[],
                   void* isrs[] )
{
    // copy spdt pins and isrs over
    for (uint8_t input = 0; input < totalInputs; input++) {
        this->InterruptServiceRoutines[input] = isrs[input];
    }
}
```

Is there a way to use this in place of a `void(*)()`. I get the error "Cannot convert lvalue of type `void*` to parameter type `void(*)()`" when I try something like this:

```
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(8), this->InterruptServiceRoutines[0], CHANGE)
```

I guess the bigger question I have is, what is the difference between `void*` and `void(*)()`? I tried searching and haven't found any answers for this. I'm assuming `void(*)()` is a pointer to a void function versus `void*` is a pointer to a void type? If so, is there a proper way to initialize an array of void function pointers?

Comment: `void(*)()` is indeed a function pointer, to a function that takes no arguments and returns `void`. `using void_fptr = void(*)(); void_fptr array[10]`. Or you can use `typedef` if `using` is not available for arduino.

Comment: There are bigger problems here than just a compilation error. Like a non-standard VLA, and, as shown, using the constructor, as is, will almost guarantee memory corruption, and a certain crash.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to use the code you have instead of a `void (*)()`.  You need to use an array of `void (*)()`.

The difference between a void * and a void (*)() is the difference between pointing to number

```
int number = 3;
```

and pointing to my_die

```
int rando() {
    return random() % 4;
}
```

This is why people say it's a really big deal.

The next major problem is that you're declaring a variable length array member without assigning it, and I don't think that works.  I think you need that to be a pointer to a set of void_fptrs, which you will need to allocate before you start setting them.

super's comment should be helpful in getting the type right. That said, they suggested a fixed length array of function pointers, which isn't consistent with your use of totalInputs. I am guessing you really want to have a dynamic array instead, based on the fact that your code is allowing for a variable number of them to be fed in. The variable length array syntax only works if you're assigning a value on declaration, either by having it be an argument to a function or by having an assignment on declaration, and you're not doing either of those here. You should be able to use **new** to allocate your dynamic void_fptr array.